# bash: can't set a variable to a solid string

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting

I cannot set a variable with a whole command-string as following:

```
A="/bin/ps wwwaux"

for a in $A
do
  echo "$a"
done
```

It assigns array instead of solid string someway.

My environment:

```
GNU/Linux, GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of a previously asked and answered question, but my search skills are failing me and I can't find the previous question.

Comment: You mean you want to save output of `/bin/ps wwwaux` into variable `A`?

Comment: @cuonglm NO. I want to put command-string as it is, with spaces, to A variable.

Comment: _"somewhy"_ That's a new one :)

Answer (score 8):

The for loop expects a list:

```
for a in $A; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Expands to:

```
for a in /bin/ps wwwaux; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Which prints both after each other. The loop runs twice, because there are **TWO** arguments. The output will be:

```
/bin/ps
wwwaux
```

Use quotes instead:

```
for a in "$A"; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

This will expands to:

```
for a in "/bin/ps wwwaux"; do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Which will loop exactly once, because it's **ONE** argument. That's the output:

```
/bin/ps wwwaux
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for f in "$A"
do
  echo $f
done
```

Your assignment is already doing what you want - it's the "for" loop that's breaking it up in a way you don't want.